# What is a payment basepoint?

Tags: lightning-network, terminology, lightning-rfc, ln-commitment-transaction

The [BOLT #3 Commitment Transaction](https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/03-transactions.md#commitment-transaction) documentation talks about a `payment basepoint`, but I can't find it defined in the glossary or anywhere else. It also mentions various other basepoints like a revocation basepoint, delayed payment basepoint, local and remote basepoints and an HTLC basepoint.

What are these basepoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basepoints are simply public keys from which all other public keys for a certain category (payments, revocation, htlcs, ..) are derived. They are used in order to deterministically generate fresh keys for each new pair of commitment transactions.

See the ["Key Derivation" section of BOLT 3](https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/03-transactions.md#keys) for details as well as for a rationale:

> Each commitment transaction uses a unique `localpubkey`, and a `remotepubkey`.
> The HTLC-success and HTLC-timeout transactions use `local_delayedpubkey` and `revocationpubkey`. [...]
>
> The reason for key change is so that trustless watching for revoked
> transactions can be outsourced. Such a *watcher* should not be able to
> determine the contents of a commitment transaction — even if the *watcher* knows
> which transaction ID to watch for and can make a reasonable guess
> as to which HTLCs and balances may be included. [...]
>
> For efficiency, keys are generated from a series of per-commitment secrets
> that are generated from a single seed, which allows the receiver to compactly
> store them.